# gwt calling java function from hand written javascript

Tags: javascript, gwt

This is with reference to this example:

```
package mypackage;

public MyUtilityClass
{
    public static int computeLoanInterest(int amt, float interestRate,
                                      int term) { ... }
    public static native void exportStaticMethod() /*-{
      $wnd.computeLoanInterest =
      $entry(@mypackage.MyUtilityClass::computeLoanInterest(IFI));
    }-*/;
}
```

I need to know the javascript code to call this function. If I use `<input type="button" onclick=computeLoanInterest(1,2.1,1)/>` the example works, but `var x = computeLoanInterest(1,2.1,1) does not work`. Can someone tell me what am I missing here.

`var x = computeLoanInterest(1,2.1,1);` makes value of x undefined
`var x = window.computeLoanInterest(1,2.1,1)` shows type mismatch error

Thanks
Ravi

Comment: does it throw" an error or just return unexpected value? (probably 0/undefined?)

Comment: value of x is undefined.

Comment: SImplest advice: get rid of $entry :) just write: `$wnd.computeLoanInterest =      @mypackage.MyUtilityClass::computeLoanInterest(IFI)` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is just get rid of $entry wrapper. Just write in your JSNI export method:

```
public static native void exportStaticMethod() /*-{
    $wnd.computeLoanInterest = @mypackage.MyUtilityClass::computeLoanInterest(IFI);
}-*/;
```

Why so?
The $entry function is defined in com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl
where it looks like (I removed the comments):

```
public static native JavaScriptObject entry(JavaScriptObject jsFunction) /*-{
    return function() {
        try {
            return @com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl::entry0(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)(jsFunction, this, arguments);
        } catch (e) {
            throw e;
        }
    };
}-*/;
```

This is nothing especially suspicious it just wraps your function with some other function but... see the entry0 method signature:

```
private static Object entry0(Object jsFunction, Object thisObj,
    Object arguments) throws Throwable
```

It returns Object - it is probably why you get type mismatch error.
And as you see the calling $entry does not add much value :).